# Fire onClick event jQuery Mobile Select Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile gives us these nice custom select menus where the menu comes in as an overlay. I'm trying to attach an onclick function to these options but since jQuery mobile replaces the option tags with their own generated tags. I can't seem to get the function to attach to the "options" (which are actually generated as styled links).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than binding to the `click` event for the "fake-option" elements, how about binding to the `change` event for the `<select>` element:

```
$('#the-select').on('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        val   = $this.val();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ39n/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

**EDIT**

If you do want to bind to the `click` event for the "fake-option" elements:

```
$('#the-page').on('click', '.ui-selectmenu-list > li', function () {
    alert('onClick = ' + $('#the-select').children().eq($(this).attr('data-option-index')).val());
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ39n/ (same demo as above)

In this example `.on()` is the same as `.delegate()`.

Comment: Binding to the 'change' event on the select is a nice fallback, but it will not always be useful since it has a very slow response. If you want to give haptic feedback (buzz on option select), then waiting with the feedback until the select menu has changed value is not useful.